# Can we make Metaplex pNFT immutable?

Tags: metaplex

I know that we can make the old Metaplex NFT standard NFT immutable. But, can the new pNFT standard become immutable as well?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the metadata of a pNFT also has a mutable flag which can be set to false similar to how it’s done for normal NFT